# VBA Sort and arrange fields

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below data in MS-Excel:

```
No1 ABC    
No2 DEF HJK 
No3 HIJ XYZ FGH   
No4 KLM
```

How can I sort it to the below using vba:

```
No1 ABC    
No2 DEF 
No2 HJK    
No3 HIJ
No3 XYZ
No3 FGH
No4 KLM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, update the source - Range("A1") and location - Range("F1") or make dynamic as appropriate:

```
Dim data() As Variant
Dim i As Double, j As Double
Dim rowOffset

Dim result As Variant
Dim results As New Collection

data = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

    For j = 2 To UBound(data, 2)

        If (Trim(data(i, j)) <> vbNullString) Then

            results.Add (data(i, 1) & "|" & data(i, j))

        End If

    Next j

Next i

For Each result In results

    With Range("F1")
        .Offset(rowOffset, 0).Value = Split(result, "|")(0)
        .Offset(rowOffset, 1).Value = Split(result, "|")(1)
    End With

    rowOffset = rowOffset + 1

Next result
```

Answer (score 1):

move line by line in the first column then apply for that line (Row)  a loop for the amount of other columns filled. Thus 2 loops should do the trick, something like:

```
Private Sub AAA()
    Dim rColumn1 As Range
    Dim rValue As Range
    Dim rTarget As Range

    Set rColumn1 = Range("A1") 'assuming your data set starts in cell A1
    Set rTarget = Range("Q1") 'assuming you want the results in columns Q and R

    Do Until IsEmpty(rColumn1.Value2)
        Set rValue = rColumn1.Offset(0, 1)
        Do Until IsEmpty(rValue.Value2)
            rTarget.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = rColumn1.Value2
            rTarget.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = rValue.Value2
            Set rTarget = rTarget.Offset(1, 0)
            Set rValue = rValue.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
        Set rColumn1 = rColumn1.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I got an indefinite loop. May I know what to set for the target? Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to offset the rColumn1, now added as second to last line in the script

Comment: for the target?  I outline how you can do this, I dont know the target (the area where you want the output put into) in YOUR excel, you will have to know this...

Comment: I have to appologize, my script was a mess, I now updated and this works like a charm